# How to suppress console output in Python?

Tags: python, sdl, pygame

I'm using Pygame/SDL's joystick module to get input from a gamepad. Every time I call its `get_hat()` method it prints to the console. This is problematic since I use the console to help me debug and now it gets flooded with `SDL_JoystickGetHat value:0:` 60 times every second. Is there a way I can disable this? Either through an option in Pygame/SDL or suppress console output while the function calls? I saw no mention of this in the Pygame documentation.

**edit:** This turns out to be due to debugging being turned on when the SDL library was compiled.

Comment: Now I'm curious what platform you are using (Linux distro?), and what package you are using? Or did you compile it yourself?

Comment: This was a long time ago, but I was using Windows, Python 2.6, and Pygame 1.9 (which includes SDL). I had just gone with their Windows installers and everything was already compiled.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's the relevant block of code from joystick.c (via SVN at http://svn.seul.org/viewcvs/viewvc.cgi/trunk/src/joystick.c?view=markup&revision=2652&root=PyGame)

```
    value = SDL_JoystickGetHat (joy, _index);
#ifdef DEBUG
    printf("SDL_JoystickGetHat value:%d:\n", value);
#endif
    if (value & SDL_HAT_UP) {
```

Looks like a problem with having debugging turned on.

Comment: How would I disable SDL debugging though Python? Google tells me the environment variable is `SDL_DEBUG` but inserting `os.environ['SDL_DEBUG'] = '0'` appears to have no effect.

Comment: @jackson that's a compile time debug option for SDL. The message is printing because when your SDL library was compiled, the DEBUG symbol was defined.

Answer (score 70):

Just for completeness, here's a nice solution from [Dave Smith's blog](http://thesmithfam.org/blog/2012/10/25/temporarily-suppress-console-output-in-python/):

```
from contextlib import contextmanager
import sys, os

@contextmanager
def suppress_stdout():
    with open(os.devnull, "w") as devnull:
        old_stdout = sys.stdout
        sys.stdout = devnull
        try:  
            yield
        finally:
            sys.stdout = old_stdout
```

With this, you can use context management wherever you want to suppress output:

```
print("Now you see it")
with suppress_stdout():
    print("Now you don't")
```

Comment: Replace all `out` by `err` to suppress warnings and error messages, compare @telotortium's answer.

Comment: For python >3.4, contextlib offers [`redirect_stdout()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/contextlib.html#contextlib.redirect_stdout) with similar functionality.

Answer (score 45):

To complete charles's answer, there are two context managers built in to python, `redirect_stdout` and `redirect_stderr` which you can use to redirect and or suppress a commands output to a file or `StringIO` variable.

```
import contextlib

with contextlib.redirect_stdout(None):
    do_thing()
```

For a more complete explanation read [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/contextlib.html#contextlib.redirect_stdout)

**A quick update:** In some cases passing `None` might raise some reference errors (e.g. `keras.models.Model.fit` calls `sys.stdout.write` which will be problematic), in that case pass an `io.StringIO()` or `os.devnull`.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. You can also add a print statement as the parameter in the redirect_stdout(). `with redirect_stdout(print('Worked!')): do_thing()`

Comment: @myidealab Since the print statement will return None, isn't that the same as just adding one before the with?

Answer (score 23):

You can get around this by assigning the standard out/error (I don't know which one it's going to) to the null device. In Python, the standard out/error files are `sys.stdout`/`sys.stderr`, and the null device is `os.devnull`, so you do

```
sys.stdout = open(os.devnull, "w")
sys.stderr = open(os.devnull, "w")
```

This should disable these error messages completely. Unfortunately, this will also disable all console output. To get around this, disable output right before calling the `get_hat()` the method, and then restore it by doing

```
sys.stdout = sys.__stdout__
sys.stderr = sys.__stderr__
```

which restores standard out and error to their original value.

Comment: I wasn't aware of this technique before. It appears to be what I want, but when I try using it the get_hat() function continues to print to the console. Could this be an issue with SDL?

Comment: Using place holders for the original sys.stdout and sys.stderr to use when restoring the stdout will extend this solution to work in situations where a 'non standard' stdout is already in place and needs to be retained after suppression. eg for use in the QGIS python console.

Comment: the first bit works, however even with the 'restoring' bit of code I still don't get any console output after it?

I'm on Ubuntu 14.04 with 3.4.3

Comment: thanks for your solution, my problem is that output is slowing down my code, will this still lead to the same slowdown?

Comment: `os.devnull` happens to be a string in python 3.6 on linux

Comment: Apparently, it throws error, `AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute '___stdout___'
a`

Answer (score 6):

Building on @charleslparker's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25061573/1904943):

```py
from contextlib import contextmanager
import sys, os

@contextmanager
def suppress_stdout():
    with open(os.devnull, "w") as devnull:
        old_stdout = sys.stdout
        sys.stdout = devnull
        try:  
            yield
        finally:
            sys.stdout = old_stdout

print("Now you see it")
with suppress_stdout():
    print("Now you don't")
```

**Tests**

```py
>>> with suppress_stdout():
        os.system('play /mnt/Vancouver/programming/scripts/PHASER.WAV')

/mnt/Vancouver/programming/scripts/PHASER.WAV:

 File Size: 1.84k     Bit Rate: 90.4k
  Encoding: Unsigned PCM  
  Channels: 1 @ 8-bit    
Samplerate: 11025Hz      
Replaygain: off         
  Duration: 00:00:00.16  

In:100%  00:00:00.16 [00:00:00.00] Out:1.79k [!=====|=====!]        Clip:0    
Done.
```

Use this to completely suppress `os.system()` output:

```py
>>> with suppress_stdout():
        os.system('play /mnt/Vancouver/programming/scripts/PHASER.WAV >/dev/null 2>&1')
>>> ## successfully executed

>>> import time
>>> with suppress_stdout():
        for i in range(3):
                os.system('play /mnt/Vancouver/programming/scripts/PHASER.WAV >/dev/null 2>&1')
                time.sleep(0.5) 
>>> ## successfully executed
```

Useful (e.g.) to signal completion of long-running scripts.

Answer (score 2):

I use pythonw.exe (on Windows) instead of python.exe.
In other OSes, you could also redirect output to /dev/nul.
And in order to still see my debug output, I am using the logging module.

Answer (score 1):

As [Demolishun](https://stackoverflow.com/users/776788/demolishun) mentions in an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7012444/disable-the-pygame-console-output) to a closed duplicate question, there is a [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7012444/disable-the-pygame-console-output) talking about this issue. The thread is from August of 2009 and one of the developers says [the debug code was left in on accident](http://archives.seul.org/pygame/users/Aug-2009/msg00310.html). I had installed Pygame 1.9.1 from pip and the debug output is still present.

To get around it for now, I downloaded the source from pygame.org, removed the print statements from src/joystick.c and compiled the code.

I am on OS X 10.7.5 for what it's worth.

Answer (score 0):

If you are on a Debian or Ubuntu machine you can just simply recompile pygame without the messages.

```
cd /tmp
sudo apt-get build-dep pygame
apt-get source pygame
vim pygame-1.9.1release+dfsg/src/joystick.c
# search for the printf("SDL.. messages and put a // in front
apt-get source --compile pygame
sudo dpkg -i python-pygame_1.9.1release+dfsg-9ubuntu1_amd64.deb
```

Greetings
Max

Answer (score 0):

The solutions using `os.devnull` could cause synchronization issues with multi-processing - so multiple processes would wait on the same resource. At least this is what I encountered in windows.

Following solution might be better:

```
class DummyOutput(object):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        pass

    def write(self, *args, **kwargs):
        pass


class suppress_stdout_stderr(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.stdout = sys.stdout
        self.stderr = sys.stderr

    def __enter__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        out = DummyOutput()
        sys.stdout = out
        sys.stderr = out

    def __exit__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        sys.stdout = self.stdout
        sys.stderr = self.stderr


with suppress_stdout_stderr():
    print(123, file=sys.stdout)
    print(123, file=sys.stderr)
```