# Disable the Pygame console Output

Tags: python, console, sdl

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to suppress console output in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2125702/how-to-suppress-console-output-in-python)

Currently I am using pygame to read joystick input and I have the following issue that I need to solve.

When calling functions in the joystick module such as `get_axis()` or `get_button()` the function prints out lines such as `SDL_JoystickGetButton value:0:` I need to disable the output of these lines to the console.

I have found the following question/answer on stackoverflow which is what I'm looking for...

[How to suppress console output in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2125702/how-to-suppress-console-output-in-python)

But this post does not supply enough information. Because if I have to turn off DEBUG, I would like to know the steps on how to do that. So far I have downloaded the pygame source and went into joystick.c and commented out the lines that print to the console, and then I ran the setup.py, but the joystick functions still print out to the console. Also I am using Python 2.6 and pygame 1.9.1.

Comment: The other software that is using the joystick output needs to use the console for displaying of various information to the user.

Answer (score 1):

This thread should resolve this:
[printf statements 1.9.1](http://archives.seul.org/pygame/users/Aug-2009/msg00110.html)

I had this same issue except when running under PyScripter it causes a huge memory leak in PyScripter itself.  So it was eating up all my memory on my machine.  Nasty interaction.