# Don't print result after calling get_axis() in pygame

Tags: python, pygame

I'm writing a code that reads the value of a joystick axis and then sends this value to an arduino. It works, however I do not want it constantly print 0 to the LXTerminal when nothing is being pressed.

The code prints: `SDL_JoystickGetAxis value:0:` repeatably when the axis is not being pressed.

It then prints:

```
SDL_JoystickGetAxis value:-32768:
SDL_JoystickGetAxis value:0:
SDL_JoystickGetAxis value:-32768:
The left drive is
-1.0
```

Repeatably when the axis is being pulled all the way down, or a number between -1 and 1 depending where the joystick is.

I only want it to print `The left drive is <leftDrive>` when the left axis is being pressed, and then nothing when it is not. How do I achieve this?

Here is my code:

```
import pygame

pygame.init()
pygame.joystick.init()
joystick = pygame.joystick.Joystick(0)
joystick.init()
leftDrive = 0
rightDrive = 0

while True:
    try:
        pygame.event.pump()

        joyCheckLeft = joystick.get_axis(1)
        joyCheckRight = joystick.get_axis(2)

        if joyCheckLeft != 0:
            pygame.event.pump()
            leftDrive = joystick.get_axis(axisLeftDrive)
            print 'The left drive is'
            print leftDrive
            writeNumber(int(2+(leftDrive*-10)))
            pygame.event.pump()
            time.sleep(0.1)

except KeyboardInterrupt:
    quit()
```

Note: The code doesn't work without `pygame.event.pump()`. This is needed so that "get_axis()" actually returns the value of the axis.

Answer (score 1):

This is related to this question [Disable the Pygame console Output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7012444/disable-the-pygame-console-output) and the thread: http://archives.seul.org/pygame/users/Aug-2009/msg00110.html This seems to have been fixed in the bitbucket source https://bitbucket.org/pygame/pygame/downloads you could try downloading the version from there.