# Suppress pygame debug output (console output)

Tags: python, python-2.7, console, pygame, suppress

Apparently the version of pygame I'm using has an issue where debug statements have been left in - [How to suppress console output in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2125702/how-to-suppress-console-output-in-python) while using `joystick.get_axis`. That is the issue, but I have been unsuccessful in trying to use the methods presented in those answers. Each of the methods still printed the `SDL_JoystickGetAxis value`.

I also tried  [this blog](http://thesmithfam.org/blog/2012/10/25/temporarily-suppress-console-output-in-python/) but I was still outputting to the console. Thinking it may be an issue with `stdout` vs `stderr`, I tried suppressing `stdout` then `stderr` then both, to no avail.

Basically my code is constantly printing `SDL_JoystickGetAxis value:0` or whatever the axis value is. How do I suppress these debug statements?

```
import os
import sys
from contextlib import contextmanager

@contextmanager
def suppress_stdout():
    with open(os.devnull, 'w') as devnull:
        old_stdout = sys.stdout
        sys.stdout = devnull 
        try:
            yield
        finally:
            sys.stdout = old_stdout
```

Later on in my code I use that function:

```
    if speedchange == False and headingchange == False:
        time.sleep(0.1)
        with suppress_stdout():
            speed_ax = joys.get_axis(1)
            head_ax = joys.get_axis(0)
```

Which still outputs debug statements

Comment: How are you using the code from the blog?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why the code from the blog you linked doesn't work, but you can always just drop this at the top of your code:

```
sys.stdout = os.devnull
sys.stderr = os.devnull
```

If you do then need to output error messages, or the like, you can just do this:

```
sys.stdout = sys.__stdout__
sys.stderr = sys.__stderr__
```

---

Just in case you are using the context manager linked in the blog wrong, this is how you're supposed to use it:

```
with suppress_stdout():
    # Do blah foo and bar here
```

Comment: I just added the code I'm using to the question. I think I am using the blog code the correct way, so I wasn't sure if debug messages have some weird special properties.

I also tried your solution, sandwiching the  `joys.get_axis` part in-between, which also did not work.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me in python 3.5 and python 2.7

```
import sys, os
stdout = sys.__stdout__
stderr = sys.__stderr__
print("start")
sys.stdout = open(os.devnull,'w')
sys.stderr = open(os.devnull,'w')
print("don't want")
sys.stdout = stdout
sys.stderr = stderr
print("want")
```

The output is

```
start
want
```